# Understanding Python super in classes

Tags: python, class, super

Please i want to understand this code, according to my understanding of super in class base programming i know its being used on the base class to access methods and attributes of the base class but here like in this code below

```
class Base:
   def __init__(self,name, age):
       self.name = name 
       self.age = age

class Sub(Base):    
    def __init__(self,name, age, first_name):
        super().__init__(name, age)
        self.first_name = first_name
```

But i cannot understand this code below seeing the super being called on the same class with the **init** function, what does this mean and how does it affect the program

```
class MyClass(object):
def __init__(self):
    super(MyClass, self).__init__()
    self.numeric_var = 1
```

Comment: `super(MyClass, self)` and `super()` are equivalent.

Comment: Please can you explained ?

Comment: It will run the `__init__` from `Base` as if it was in `Sub`. It is effectively the same in this case as doing `self.name = name`, `self.age = age`, `self.first_name = first_name`, but it's split over two classes.

Comment: @adedesmond: `super()` without arguments has the same result as `super(CurrentClass, self)`, for almost all normal use.